# Casting a 1D dynamic array to IplImage's imageData data type using reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, opencv, casting

I used this code snippet for casting IplImage data to a dynamic array.

`unsigned char *data = reinterpret_cast <unsigned char*> (image->imageData);`

How can I do the reverse of it ?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unsigned char *entrypoint;
...
image->imageData = entrypoint;

Make sure to update:
image->widthStep,
image->width,
image->height,
image->nChannels, etc.